# (PostgreSQL) Copying from CSV when all the date from a "column" are reference (foreign keys) from another table

Tags: postgresql, csv, import, copy, key

I'm using the Copy  form to import date in my Database and it works fine when I'm using it on tables with no triggers or reference to other tables. 
When there are I get the Message:

```
"Query returned successfully: 0 rows affected, xxxx ms execution time"
```

When I disable all reference triggers (Foreign keys) and UpdRel It works, but their columns returns empty.

The tables were created using a CMDB software (CMDBuild) and the reference columns have an Integer type, in other words, I'm trying to import Integer numbers which are the same as a "code" Column from another table.

The copy form I'm using:

```
COPY "TableName"("Col1","Col2","Col3"...) FROM 'C:\file.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV;
```

An example of the Tables:

table1:

```
Name: Servers
Attributes: Code(Referenced1), Description, Operational_System, IP, Domain, etc
```

table2:

```
Name: Hard_Disk
Attributes: Code(Referenced2), Description, Size, Interface, Serial, etc
```

table3

```
Name: Servers_X_HD
Attributes: Code, Description, Server(Reference1), Hard_Disk(Reference2), Size, etc..
```

I have successfully imported all Servers and HD data, I'm Having trouble importing table3 which have the foreign keys triggers.

I'm sorry if It's confusing, I'm not really that familiar with SQL or coding in general, I'm mostly a google-search-learner, besides a quick Java course I took.

If there is any info anyone needs to help me, I'll gladly provide within my reach..

Comment: Your version of Postgres? And the preferred form for table definitions is what you get with `\d tbl` in `psql`.

Comment: Postgres 9.2 (x86).

I'm not sure about what you want on table definitions, is it this:

    Schema: Public | Name: HD_Servidor | Type: table | Owner postgres

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered the issue. There was another column on all of those tables labelled "id" that was what was being used to be the reference for foreign keys.

The "code" column was just used as a "disguise" and to facilitate the user viewing of CMDBuild (by using defined integer numbers by the user, instead of the randomly generated "ids" by postgres).

By replacing the numbers of the "code" column with the ones on the "id" column, I managed to copy the info from the CSVs with no issues.